# How to make reusable components in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, components, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to create a TextField reusable component so I did this

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldComponent(state: Any, placeholder: String) {
    TextField(
        value = state,
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue -> state = textFieldValue },
        placeholder = { Text(placeholder, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary) }
    )
}
```

but I'm getting these errors

[image]

and that's how I'm calling the component

```
val textFieldState by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
TextFieldComponent(state = textFieldState, placeholder = "Email")
```

so is there any fix?

Comment: In your `TextFieldComponent()`, `state` cannot be `Any`. It is going to need to be a type that `TextField()` supports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just turn `state` into a `MutableState<String>`, so you can modify it from inside the function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TextFieldComponent(state: MutableState<String>, placeholder: String) {
    TextField(
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue -> state.value = textFieldValue },
        placeholder = { Text(placeholder, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary) }
    )
}
```

However, it is usually preferable to instead provide a value and a change listener to the composable function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TextFieldComponent2(value: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit, placeholder: String) {
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue -> onValueChange(textFieldValue) },
        placeholder = { Text(placeholder, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary) }
    )
}
```

Such solution is more flexible as the caller could very easily provide any behavior on the value change (thanks @Jakoss)

Comment: Please don't. That's against the most core rule the compose - hoist state. The function should get a onValueChange as a parameter

Comment: @Jakoss I'm far from being a Compose expert, but why do you think it is not hoisted? `TextFieldComponent` does not hold its own state here. It receives it from its caller. `MutableState` here acts as a value provider and a value change callback and I believe it is effectively the same as receiving them separately. Official documentation even provides examples about state holders that are passed to composable functions. How is it different?

Comment: The difference is that caller cannot control that state in any way. It just provides a bag for the data. This is not a pattern for a reusable composable and I saw not a single one in material or ui libraries. It's just not as flexible and imo it's just inferior. It does the same thing basically, but gives the caller a control over the process

Comment: Yes, I agree, change listener is more flexible. I provided such solution just because OP's original solution was almost a working one. But you are right - I should at least mention that this is not the usual way to do this. Thanks, I updated the answer.